# Just upgraded to Blender 3.5, now there's a select menu everytime I hit Alt+LMB, how do I get this to go away?

Tags: interface, select, pie-menu

This is the little menu that pops up every time I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. I do not like it, it gets in the way and is distracting to my workflow. Anyone know how to get rid of this?

I use the Industry compatible keymap since I originally learned Maya.

It would be very much appreciated!

[image: See Image Here]

Comment: You already got an answer below, just in general for the next time you have a shortcut you want to change/disable: go to _Edit_ > _Preferences_ > _Keymap_, there at the top switch the filter method from _Name_ to _Key-Binding_. Now you can (in the above case) enter `alt lmb` in the search field and you will find all uses of this shortcut in all editors.

Answer (score 4):

[image: answer]

Unchecking this option in preferences fixed the issue.